# Model not updating on form submit, using Backbone + Stickit

Tags: backbone.js, data-binding, backbone-stickit

I'm trying to use the [backbone.stickit](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/) library to bind my form input to the model but can't seem to get the model to update correctly.

The keyup event appears to work correctly, i can see the value change if i use the "onSet" callback to display it:

```
    bindings: {
        '#firstName': {
            observe: 'firstName',
            onSet: function(val, options) {
                $('#output').html(val);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my code ([Run it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9d39rrk/)):

HTML

```
<div id="view">
    <form name="form" id="form">
        <input id="firstName" type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = {

    Model: Backbone.Model.extend({
        firstName: 'test'
    }),

    View: Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#view",

        initialize: function(){ 
            this.model = new app.Model();
            this.render(); 
        }, 
        bindings: {
            '#firstName': 'firstName'
        },        
        render: function(){ 
            this.$el.html( this.template ); 
            this.stickit();
        }, 
        events: {
            "submit #form": "submitForm"
        },

        submitForm: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#output').html('output:'+this.model.firstName);
        }

    })
};

var view = new app.View();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of getting a model attribute is usally not by accessing the attribute name as an object property, the way you did it `this.model.firstName`. personally I know a very few cases of such implemntation. The so called right way to do that is by using `get` method:
`this.model.get("firstName")`. 
This will return the current model value.

I usually define getters and setters for each model I use, so I would do the following:

```
getFirstName: function(){
    return this.get("firstName");
}
```

Just looks better and more "easy on the eyes" :) (but totally not a must)

Here's an update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srhfvs8h/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it.  I can't believe i missed that, makes perfect sense :-)